# Tool to count the bindings on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have been tasked with optimizing a web site recently.  One thing I suspect is that there are way too many events bound to different objects on the web site.  Like each item in a grid having an event bound to it's double click event.  This slows down the rendering as it has to set up a binding for each item as things are added.  I would expect we could do something like a doubleclick on a grid binding and then determine the item clicked.

Anyway, the client is asking for metrics on things.  I need to be able to give them some kind of report that says there are X events bound on the page currently.  My change takes it down to Y number of bindings.

Is there any tool out there that you know of that can give me that kind of count?  I thought about the event listeners tab on the elements view of chrome developer tools, but I wasn't sure if that listed all the events and if so, how to export the list out to get a count.

Comment: While not an answer to your actual question, Look into event delegation.  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I understand event delegation just fine.  Please read the actual question and understand that I am inheriting an app where the apparently do not.  I am not asking how to speed it up, I am asking how to count the events so I can report numbers back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event) gives you an overview of all events bound on a particular page.

If you are running chrome you can also get bound events on a DOM node using the command line API:

```
getEventListeners(el); // {click: [..], mouseover: [..], ...}
```

This feature can be wrapped in something like:

```
// Run this in your console:
var count = 0;
// forEach on all elements in the DOM:
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).forEach(function(el) {
    // count all bound events using `getEventListeners`
    var events = getEventListeners(el);
    for ( var prop in events ) count += events[prop].length;
});
console.log('Total events bound: %d', count);
```

Hope you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

To count bindings on an element:

```
var count = 0;
$('#myTable *').each(function () {
    $.each(getEventListeners(this), function () {
        count += this.length;
    });
});
console.log(count + ' bindings in #myTable');
```

To optimize, you will be able to do this:

With raw JS:

```
document.getElementById('myTable').onclick = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target); // Contains the clicked TD tag element
};
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#mayTable').on('click', 'td', function() {
    console.log(this); // Contains the clicked TD tag element
});
```

This will decrease bindings from columns * lines of your grid to 1.

Comment: `Object.keys(getEventListeners(this))` will only gives you numbers of different events bound. But will not count if the same element have multiply `click`-events bound.

Comment: A bit less precise but faster.

Comment: I dont think speed & performance is a matter when you are **debugging** speed & performance. :)